# store and display image in sqlite in windows store app?

Tags: sqlite, windows-store-apps

I have a form from which I want to store an image to my sqlite database and then i want it to be displayed at another page as grid background.
I am making an windows store app so I am using xaml and c#.
I want the stored image as my gridview background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your Image to database with 2 ways-

1. By converting image to `byte[]`

   1. convert Image to bytes[] and save it to sqlite Blob type parameter.
   2. get that Blob datatype and store again to byte[] and then convert to Image
2. By converting image to base64 string

   1. Convert image to base64 string store to sqlite in varchar/varchar2 type
   2. get base64 string from sqlite db and convert to image

Comment: can I have the sample code for this problem??
I am a beginner so I don't know where to write the code and how to pass the variables.?

Answer (score 1):

You can store it as a base64 encoded image, when you need to show it, you must to decode the image.

try reading [this](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Base-64 is best encoding technique to store images in SQLite. Try the below given code. One method will give you base-64 encoded string of `StorageFile` & other one will return you `BitmapImage` object, which can be set as source of `<Image />`.

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> Base64StringToBitmap(string source)
{
    var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
    var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
    dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
    ims.Seek(0);
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.SetSource(ims);
    return img;
}

private async Task<string> ConvertStorageFileToBase64String(StorageFile imageFile)
{
    var stream = await imageFile.OpenReadAsync();

    using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream))
    {
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
        await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: can I have the sample code for this problem?? I am a beginner so I don't know where to write the code and how to pass the variables.?